# Font issue when hovering

Tags: html, css, fonts, hover, font-face

https://i.stack.imgur.com/D3plE.png
I'm using lobster font (I know, it's horrible) for a navigation bar for a client and when the link is static it is missing the end of some of the letters but when I hover the entire letter appears, I don't have any widths set to the links so its not like they're hidden behind a box or anything...
I've attached an image, the top image being normal link and the bottom being hover.
I basically want it to have all parts of the letters, like in the bottom image.

normal has an opacity of 0.4 with a text shadow and the hover state has an opacity of 0.7 if that helps.

```
.links a {
color:white!important; 
text-shadow: 1px 2px 0px black;
opacity:0.7;
}


.links a:hover {
opacity:1;
}


<h2 class="center links"><a href="#">Contact</a></h2>
```

js fiddle here with lobster being used http://jsfiddle.net/JSbdh/
although, it doesnt seem to be an issue on there, which makes it even weirder

Comment: add relative html, css and [jsfiddle example](http://www.jsfiddle.net)

Comment: Your images are missing.

Comment: Not being an issue on jsfiddle normally means you have other code that is making the issue. Copy all code over instead of just the part you think is affecting it

Comment: @simon added now i think, couldnt add it cos of reputation, but the static link should work and

Comment: @andy I have a few css files and lines of html, would it be easier if I quickly upload the webpage and link that so inspect element could be used? or link the css files individually

Comment: @Andy It is an issue on jfiddle, the end of the t is still missing it just isnt fixed on hover, just realised that

Comment: @AlexNewman Yep, uploading the page is fine

Comment: @andy http://alexn.co.uk/Paradice/index.html it's after the transition has stopped the rest of the letter appears

Comment: Just as a side note: when I open this page, FF jumps to permanent 50% cpu usage and it's extremely laggy when scrolling. You may want to optimize some js code, just an interval for the slider cannot produce that much cpu consumption.

Comment: @simon i'm a massive js noob, how would i go about doing this?

Comment: Well it's probably because you're loading flexslider twice, minified and unminified.